# Is there a more correct way to show explicit exponential operators?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I typed in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103411/number-of-distinct-values-taken-by-alpha-alpha-dots-alpha-with) like this:

```
$\underbrace{\alpha \hat{\phantom{\hat{}}} \alpha \hat{\phantom{\hat{}}} \dots \hat{\phantom{\hat{}}} \alpha}_\text{n times}$
```

which `mathjax` prints as

[image: example output]

I feel there should be a more correct way to do this.

Comment: I am not sure that that is such a good idea since exponentiation is not associative: `2^(3^2)` is not the same as `(2^3)^2)`.  So what exactly does `2^3^2` mean?  This is probably the reason why TeX complains about double super scripts.

Comment: @PeterGrill if you look at the linked question, you'll see that the expression is referring to the number of possible results with parentheses inserted in all possible ways.

Answer (score 10):

You could also type

```
\def\mhat{\mathbin{\hat{\vphantom{x}}}} % spacing like a binary operator 
$\underbrace{\alpha\mhat\alpha\mhat\cdots\mhat\alpha}_{\text{$n$ times}}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a circumflex (hat) symbol intended for use in maths mode, except as an accent. However, you can use the text mode version `\textasciicircum` (or alternatively just `\^{}`). This avoids the need for phantoms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mathcirc{\text{\textasciicircum}}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\alpha \mathcirc \alpha \mathcirc  \ldots \mathcirc \alpha}_{n\text{ times}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you might like to use

```
\newcommand\expon{\mathbin {^\wedge}}
```

or, if you're quite flexible about the symbol you use, adopt Knuth's up-arrow notation:

```
\newcommand\expon {\mathbin {\uparrow}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant without hat that counts the exponential operations:

```
$\bigl(\bigl(\bigl(\alpha
\underbrace{
  ^\alpha\bigr)^\alpha\bigr)^{\cdots}\bigr)^\alpha
}_\text{$n$ times}
= \alpha^{(\alpha^n)}$
```

> [image]

Comment: But the idea of the OP is not to include the parentheses explicitly; the OP is defining an expression for counting all possible different values obtained by inserting parentheses in every possible way in the original expression.

Comment: I think that it would be better to add centered dots after the first parenthesis : `\bigl(\cdots\bigl(\bigl(...`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Heiko's answer, but without the parentheses:

```
\alpha
\underbrace{
  {{{^{\alpha\vphantom{h}}}^{\alpha\vphantom{h}}}^{\cdots\vphantom{h}}}^{\alpha\vphantom{h}}
}_{\text{$n$ times}}
= \alpha^{(\alpha^n)}
```

[image]

(A `\strut` instead of `\vphantom{h}` gives me too much vertical space.)

(Probably better with `\!` after the initial `\alpha`.)

Comment: This unfortunately misses the point of the OP in the same way as Heiko's answer; with the additional problem that the equation you write is incorrect.

Comment: The notation without parenthesis is very ambiguous.

Comment: @projetmbc But wasn't it the point? I thought the OP wanted an expression where parentheses could be inserted in every possible way. (Of course, I copied the equation from Heiko, so the equality only holds for a particular way of inserting the parentheses, but I thought the LHS is what the OP wanted to express.)

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: As Jellby just explained, only the LHS is important here. (Ok, then maybe he should remove the RHS). Any way, I think this is a great way of writing the expression, as you don't need to define a new exponentiation operator.

Comment: Umm... When you have an actual vertical tower of exponents, the fact that there are no parentheses doesn't make it ambiguous. The exponents are then evaluated top-down. For instance. If \alpha=2 and n=3, the result would be 16 (or 2^4). That's standard mathematical notation. It's when you introduce an explicit, non-associative boolean symbol as in the OP that ambiguity arises.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Well, OK, there's a convention to evaluate the parenthesis-less expression. That doesn't alter the fact that by adding parentheses in different places you can get different results, does it?

Comment: When you add parentheses, you would drop some of the exponents down in writing them. Please accept that what occurs on the left-hand side, when written as a vertical tower, is unambiguous to mathematicians, for the same reason that there is no ambiguity whether *ax+b* means *(ax)+b* or *a(x+b)* despite the lack of parentheses. All notation is convention, and towers of exponents are notation with a well-defined meaning to mathematicians.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I accept that, but just as you can add parentheses to ax+b (and one of the possibilities is the same as the expression without parentheses), you can add parentheses to the tower of exponents and that changes the meaning in most cases. When adding a parenthesis, maybe the exponents should drop, but that doesn't change the meaning (I mean, once the parenthesis is there, the height of the exponent is a purely typographical/aesthetic matter).